# How to translate "Пройтись по тексту"?

Tags: перевод, словоупотребление

What is the possible translation of the phrase "Пройтись по тексту".

Comment: It's interesting that everything I see a title that seems interesting, and usually something that I would love to know, you all put it on hold. I think you're trigger-happy. I just learned something from Romaklimenko's response - isn't that the point of this site?

Comment: Nowhere in his post does he mention English - he just wants an interpretation, explanation, translation, etc. The sad thing is that if he changed the word "translation" to something else, you would accept the question, which is unbelievably petty. This is why I don't use this site anymore - I'm afraid to ask anything.

Answer (score 3):

Skim the text.

Or "scan the text". But "skim" has closer meaning.

Comment: @Romakimenko: Thank you. That sounds like our expression: give something the "once-over"